# zip creates empty files if run from cron

Tags: linux, zip, cron, archive

I have simple script which should create archive from 3 csv files. 
If I run script from cmd it works perfect, if I cron this script then i am getting archive with 3 empty files inside.

this is the part of the script (I ommited part where script working with files):

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/zip -j Inroamers_$(date +"%m_%d_%Y") /folder/*

#echo "Dear Colleagues, ......." | mail -s "Inroamers report for $(date +"%m%d%Y")" -a /folder/Inroamers_$(date +"%m_%d_%Y").zip myname@mymail.com
```

From zip output i can see:

```
  adding: folder/Inroamers_04_24_2017.csv (stored 0%)
  adding: folder/Inroamers_04_24_2017.csv (stored 0%)
  adding: folder/Inroamers_04_24_2017.csv (stored 0%)
```

Same situation if I am using

```
/bin/tar -cvf file.gz *
```

Any ideas why i am getting this problem?

Comment: I already made chmod 777 for test purposes for all folders and files which used in this script.

Answer (score 0):

There no problems with zip, but sed doesnt work, so this question should be closed.